# Why stick footer approach not working on Safari 13.0.5 version

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer, sticky-footer

I want my footer div and copyright section fixed at bottom only. And when someone scroll down, then footer fixed at bottom only and my page-wrapper (body section) will move-up with footer heights only.
For that I am trying with below code and it works well in all browsers except Safari (I have 13.0.5 safari version with me).

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
{
body #page_wrapper, body.boxed #page_wrapper{
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:420px;
    background:#ffffff;
    z-index:1;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1200px)
{
.site-footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
}
```

In safari browser, I just shows blank space over there at footer section.

I am using media query, because I want sticky-footer approach only on large devices not for mobile devices.
Suggest me what can I do?  So that I can be able to reflect the same on safari as well.

Please let me know, If do you want any other clarification to understand my concern.

Comment: Try changing the media query syntax to '@media screen and (min-width: 1200px){...}'. Also I hope you can remove 'z-index:-1;' of '.site-footer'

Comment: refer -> https://philipwalton.com/articles/normalizing-cross-browser-flexbox-bugs/

Comment: @pons I had tried changing with media query syntax, still it's not reflecting. Even I have removed media query and test it, it will work as it is. And when I removed "z-index:-1" from site footer, So my footer become first (like header)  and fixed at bottom and my page data will hide behind my footer. that is why I used 'z-index:1' for page content and 'z-index:-1' for site footer.

Comment: could you share a code where issue issue can be reproduced?

Comment: Refer this link: indemortgage.staging.wpengine.com

Comment: @Pons, Is it related with browser or code?

Comment: Hi @pons, Is there any option to disable above css for safari browser only? So that I can show the default footer layout for safari instead of blank footer. Please suggest. Appreciate for your help.